# expand collapse whole row

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Currently I am expanding/collapsing using +/- icon.  I am using Repeater inside Repeater to get the required output. How can I expand/collapse whole row rather than only on icon click.

Below is the code:

```html
<asp:Repeater ID="repDietStandards" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table  id="userTable" class="table">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="trtest"> <%-- onclick="test()">--%>
            <td class="bkclr"> 
            <img id="imgpn" alt="" class="dietassmnt_imgpn_hs testp" src="../images/N_Images/plus.png" /> 
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlNutDtl" runat="server" class="pnldisplay">
                <asp:Repeater ID="repDietStandardsDtl" runat="server" DataSource='<%#GetCalorieChildData(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("SNo"))) %>' OnItemDataBound="repDietStandardsDtl_ItemDataBound">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table class="ChildGrid accordion_body table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                       <th class="dietact_tbltd2_hs">Description</th>
                       <th class="dietact_tbltd2_hs">Qty</th>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lblCalorieLP" Text='<%#Eval("CompareOn") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                            <td class="alncenter"><asp:Label ID="lblConsumption" Text='<%#(Convert.ToString(Eval("FirstItem"))=="0") ? "nil" : Eval("FirstItem") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>                                       
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

JS:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("body").on("click", "[src*=plus]", function () { //Hierarical Repeater to display Recommended Diet functionality
            $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
            $(this).attr("src", "../images/N_Images/minus.png");
        });
        $("body").on("click", "[src*=minus]", function () {  //Hierarical Repeater to display Recommended Diet functionality
            $(this).attr("src", "../images/N_Images/plus.png");
            $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
        });
</script>
```

In .cs:

```js
private void BndDefaultRecommendedDiet(int selDiet=1)
        {
  repDietStandards.DataSource = lstRecommendedDietTH;
             repDietStandards.DataBind();
}

  public List<CompareCalorie> GetCalorieChildData(int serialNo)  //Populate Child Repeater repDietStandardsDtl
        {
            List<CompareCalorie> lstRequiredNutrients = null;
            if (lstReqNutrient != null)
                lstRequiredNutrients = lstReqNutrient.Where(x => x.SNo == serialNo).ToList();

            return lstRequiredNutrients;
        }
```

I am trying to expand/collapse whole row rather then only on plus/minus icon click.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A few pointers - if you don't format your question correctly, people can't read it - that involves correctly marking code blocks  and indenting the code so that most of it is visible. You also need to tag all of the relevant languages so that people see it. As you have only tagged 'collapse' and 'expand' and not, for example, JavaScript, you're severely limiting your audience (for reference, 'collapse' has 6 watchers, 'expand' has 9 and 'JavaScript' has 2,000,000. It would be a good idea to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. Below is the updated code.

```html
<asp:Repeater ID="repDietStandards" runat="server">

    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="userTable" class="table">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="trtest"> 
            <td class="bkclr"> 
            <img id="imgpn" alt="" class="dietassmnt_imgpn_hs testp" src="../images/N_Images/plus.png" /> 
                <asp:Label ID="lblHead" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%#Eval("Heading") %>' />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlNutDtl" runat="server" class="chld pnldisplay">
                <asp:Repeater ID="repDietStandardsDtl" runat="server" DataSource='<%#GetCalorieChildData(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("SNo"))) %>' OnItemDataBound="repDietStandardsDtl_ItemDataBound">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table class="ChildGrid accordion_body table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                       <th class="dietact_tbltd2_hs">Description</th>
                       <th class="dietact_tbltd2_hs">Qty</th>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lblCalorieLP" Text='<%#Eval("CompareOn") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                            <td class="alncenter"><asp:Label ID="lblConsumption" Text='<%#(Convert.ToString(Eval("FirstItem"))=="0") ? "nil" : Eval("FirstItem") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>                                       
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </asp:Panel>
            </td>
           <%-- <td class="accordion_head"><asp:Label ID="lblHead" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%#Eval("Heading") %>' /></td>--%>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tbody>
        </table>                                       
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

JS Changes:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("body").on("click", ".bkclr", function () {
        // get the current row
        var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
        currentRow.find('.chld').toggleClass('pnldisplay');
        if (currentRow.find('.testp').attr("src").trim() == "../images/N_Images/plus.png")
            currentRow.find('.testp').attr("src", "../images/N_Images/minus.png");
        else
            currentRow.find('.testp').attr("src", "../images/N_Images/plus.png");
    });
```

Comment: In addition to the above comments - in an answer it would be much more helpful if you explain why/how your code has solved the problem, to help people understand your solution clearly.